# UIImage choose from image library iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I would like to choose any picture from image gallery instead of the one named "mona-lisa" located in Assets. Is it possible?

```
func addPainting(_ hitResult: ARHitTestResult, _ grid: Grid) {

    // 1.
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.35)
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "mona-lisa")
    planeGeometry.materials = [material]

    // 2.
    let paintingNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
    paintingNode.transform = SCNMatrix4(hitResult.anchor!.transform)
    paintingNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(paintingNode.eulerAngles.x + (-Float.pi / 2), paintingNode.eulerAngles.y, paintingNode.eulerAngles.z)
    paintingNode.position = SCNVector3(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(paintingNode)
    grid.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `UIImagePickerController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned above you can use UIImagePickerController for picking images from image gallery.

Here small example how to use it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


@IBAction func loadImageButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary // The defined source type means the you take images from system gallery.

    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])  {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = pickedImage // Here you have the image which was picked in gallery.
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Comment: that seems to be a good answer, but based on that particular example, how can I use the picked image as material.diffuse.contents ?

Comment: for showing image picker you need to have view controller on which you can present it. I don't know what the class where you operate with material.diffuse.contents, maybe if you send me structure of the class I may help you.